# Android dynamic link intent not clear after open app

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

Im using firebase dynamic link on my app. This is my code in my Splash Activity.

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
                .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                })
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                        Uri deepLink = null;
                        if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                            deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                            if (deepLink != null && !deepLink.toString().equals("")) {
                                getContent(deepLink.toString());
                            } else {
                                setSettings();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

And this is my manifest file

```
<activity android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="Title" android:autoVerify="true"
            tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Im handling the dynamic link intent and redirect an activity from SplashActivity. After that im back MainActivity in my app and get background the app. After that, im opening app again and directly redirect dynamic link activity again from splash. If i click another dynamic link, still redirect first dynamic link activity. I cant clear first dynamic link from app. What can i do about it ?

Comment: You could manually override (clear) the intent with `setIntent(null);`

Comment: Also, you could `finish()` the SplashActivity once the deeplink has been handled.